# ng-repeat over multidimensional array in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, multidimensional-array, angularjs-ng-repeat

Hello i have the following JSON returned from my server:

```
{
    "travelSchedules":{
        "VIP":[
            {"id":1,"travel_company_id":1,"travel_route_id":3,"class":"VIP","fare":300,"reporting_time":"09:00:00","departure_time":"09:15:00","weekday":"Mon","end_date":"2015-07-24","is_active":1,"created_at":"2015-07-23 15:46:14","updated_at":"2015-07-23 15:46:14","deleted_at":null},
            {"id":3,"travel_company_id":1,"travel_route_id":3,"class":"VIP","fare":300,"reporting_time":"09:00:00","departure_time":"09:15:00","weekday":"Wed","end_date":"2015-07-24","is_active":1,"created_at":"2015-07-23 15:46:14","updated_at":"2015-07-23 15:46:14","deleted_at":null},
            {"id":5,"travel_company_id":1,"travel_route_id":3,"class":"VIP","fare":300,"reporting_time":"09:00:00","departure_time":"09:15:00","weekday":"Thu","end_date":"2015-07-24","is_active":1,"created_at":"2015-07-23 15:46:15","updated_at":"2015-07-23 15:46:15","deleted_at":null},
            {"id":7,"travel_company_id":1,"travel_route_id":3,"class":"VIP","fare":300,"reporting_time":"09:00:00","departure_time":"09:15:00","weekday":"Fri","end_date":"2015-07-24","is_active":1,"created_at":"2015-07-23 15:46:15","updated_at":"2015-07-23 15:46:15","deleted_at":null},
            {"id":9,"travel_company_id":1,"travel_route_id":3,"class":"VIP","fare":300,"reporting_time":"09:00:00","departure_time":"09:15:00","weekday":"Sat","end_date":"2015-07-24","is_active":1,"created_at":"2015-07-23 15:46:15","updated_at":"2015-07-23 15:46:15","deleted_at":null}
        ],
        "VVIP":[
            {"id":2,"travel_company_id":1,"travel_route_id":3,"class":"VVIP","fare":450,"reporting_time":"09:00:00","departure_time":"09:15:00","weekday":"Mon","end_date":"2015-07-24","is_active":1,"created_at":"2015-07-23 15:46:14","updated_at":"2015-07-23 15:46:14","deleted_at":null},
            {"id":4,"travel_company_id":1,"travel_route_id":3,"class":"VVIP","fare":450,"reporting_time":"09:00:00","departure_time":"09:15:00","weekday":"Wed","end_date":"2015-07-24","is_active":1,"created_at":"2015-07-23 15:46:14","updated_at":"2015-07-23 15:46:14","deleted_at":null},
            {"id":6,"travel_company_id":1,"travel_route_id":3,"class":"VVIP","fare":450,"reporting_time":"09:00:00","departure_time":"09:15:00","weekday":"Thu","end_date":"2015-07-24","is_active":1,"created_at":"2015-07-23 15:46:15","updated_at":"2015-07-23 15:46:15","deleted_at":null},
            {"id":8,"travel_company_id":1,"travel_route_id":3,"class":"VVIP","fare":450,"reporting_time":"09:00:00","departure_time":"09:15:00","weekday":"Fri","end_date":"2015-07-24","is_active":1,"created_at":"2015-07-23 15:46:15","updated_at":"2015-07-23 15:46:15","deleted_at":null},
            {"id":10,"travel_company_id":1,"travel_route_id":3,"class":"VVIP","fare":450,"reporting_time":"09:00:00","departure_time":"09:15:00","weekday":"Sat","end_date":"2015-07-24","is_active":1,"created_at":"2015-07-23 15:46:15","updated_at":"2015-07-23 15:46:15","deleted_at":null}
        ]
    }
}
```

Which i assign to $scope.travelSchedules in my application.
Now i want to loop through the data and display each group in a single table. like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="group in groups">
  <h1>VIP</h1>
    <table>
      <tr ng-repeat="row in VIP">
        ...
      </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<div ng-repeat="group in groups">
  <h1>VVIP</h1>
    <table>
      <tr ng-repeat="row in VIP">
        ...
      </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Please note here that the groups i am referring to are: VIP, VVIP
They are loaded dynamically from the server meaning there can be more than these 2.

Also each group name is actually a 'key' in the array. I do not know how to go about this sadly.

Edit: **VIP** and **VVIP** are **just placeholders**, the code i posted is actually just to show what i want to achieve, looking at my array my issue is how do i get to display the names 'VIP and 'VVIP' as headers for each table in the loop?

Comment: I have added an answer with working reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `travelSchedules` is an object, so you need key value pair to iterate on it. The key will be `VIP` or `VVIP` or anything that json returns and value will be corresponding `array`. Now, you will need to iterate on that array to paint data. You need to update your html to following

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in travelSchedules">
    <h1>{{key}}</h1>
    <table>
      <tr ng-repeat="row in value">
        ...
      </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

For reference - http://plnkr.co/edit/nou8baooWz6cG1UjZXPT?p=preview

Comment: Thanks, exactly what i was looking for! :D

Answer (score 1):

In an ng-repeat you can get access to the key like so:

```
<tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in data">
    <th>{{ key }}</th>
    <td>{{ value}}</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this -

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<div ng-repeat="(key, val) in travelSchedules">
     <h1>{{key}}</h1>
        <table ng-repeat="group in val">
            <tr ng-repeat="row in group"><td>{{row}}</td></tr>
        </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

See fiddle for example - http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/15846/

Comment: I just updated my post, VIP and VVIP are just placeholders since i dunno what i supposed to go there, i want to be able to dynamically display those 'keys' as text to be used for each table header.

Comment: @user3718908 then strip the keys, updated answer (Added a fiddle too)

Comment: I tried that but instead of displaying the key names it displayed numbers: 0,1. Plus in your fiddle it just re-displays the JSON in the result there is no header.

Comment: @user3718908 updated again - try that fiddle see if that's what you want